# assets are not loading in codeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Im new to codeIgnitor and trying to load assets folder css into my header.php.
Before i post this question i have searched everywhere and im doing correctly what everyone saying. but still when i load the page css file not loading.

I have `.htaccess` in following way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

in `Config.php`

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog';`
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

in `autoload.php`

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form','text');`

in `Controllers->Pages.php`

```
class Pages extends CI_controller{
    public function view($page = 'home'){
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
  }
```

in `header.php`

```
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/main.css">
  </head>
```

#### But When i load the page everything works well without css.

in source i can see style url is also set correctly. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog/assets/css/main.css">`
but when i click on it its broken.

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)` restart apache. still an issue?

Comment: @Alex i tried it. it gave me 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Stanzi1791 still issue is same

Comment: a css file is giving you an internal server error?? that's more than odd. it's not a script. e.g. going to `http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog/assets/css/main.css` you see a 500?

Comment: @Alex no no. after removing `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)` i got 500 error when load normal `http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog`

Comment: If you change the href of the link to /assets/css/main.css, do you still experience the same problem?

Comment: i suggested removing that because i've never seen that condition used before with codeigniter. i don't use it, and not having it doesn't give me a 500. sanity check: does the file actually exist?

Comment: @LajosArpad i removed `<?php echo base_url();?>` and tried. but issue is still there.

Comment: @Alex yes. you can see it in the screenshot as well. i was studying tutorial. its to remove index.php on url i guess ex : `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/demoblog/index.php/home` to `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/demoblog/home`

Comment: yea but doing that shouldn't affect apache's ability to serve files. are u sure `main.css` isn't actually `main.txt.css` or something? at this point if you can't directly access it via `http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog/assets/css/main.css` you can rule out codeigniter entirely. try deleting the htaccess and seeing if you can access it directly then (and restart apache)

Comment: @Alex i just again download css from bootstrap and added again from creating new assets. its still same.

Comment: if after removing your htaccess file and restarting your localhost program xampp or wampp or whatever and you still can't access it directly and you are sure the path is correct we can be sure that there is something terribly wrong with your localhost system and I cannot tell you what that issue might be as the fact that it serving php files yet not serving css defies logic to me

Comment: @Alex i tried with deleting. but issue was same. ill try reinstalling server again.

Comment: what happen when you open this link?
http://localhost/codeigniter/demoblog/assets/css/main.css

Comment: @RaheelKhan `This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.`

Comment: okay and what happen when you comment the .htaccess code?

Comment: @RaheelKhan same error.

Comment: you're facing this issue in only this project, or also in other projects?

Comment: Oh its because of this damn port number on localhost i didn't notice that. im using MAMP and it has http://localhost:8888. once i changed `base_url` to `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/demoblog` it worked. thanks @Alex and all the others.